# get calculation on dynamic add row in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, calculation, tablerow

Im having a problem with my input box not showing any values.

```js
var renumber = 0;

function addItem() {
  renumber++;
  var html = "<tr";
  html += "<td id='itemNum'>" + renumber + "</td>";
  html += "<td><input name='itemName[]'></td>";
  html += "<td><input name='itemDescription[]'></td>";
  html += "<td><span class='currency'>$</span><input id='perHour' value='0' name='amountPerHour[]'></td>";
  html += "<td><input id='lineHours' value='0' name='hours[]'></td>";
  html += "<td><span class='currency'>$</span><input id='lineTotal' onblur='lineTotal(this);' value='0' name='lineTotal[]'></td>";
  html += "<td><button type='button' id='remove_button' onclick='removeItem();'> X </button></td>";
  html += "</tr>";
  document.getElementById("addItems").insertRow().innerHTML = html;
}

function removeItem() {
  document.getElementById("addItems").deleteRow(0);
  renumber--;
  var reorder = tblRow.rows;
  for(var i = 0; i < reorder.length; i++) {
    renumber[i];
    renumber++;
  }
  document.getElementById("itemNum").innerHTML = renumber;
}

function lineTotal(elem) {
  var mainRow = document.getElementById(elem);
  var AmtPerHour = mainRow.getElementsByTagName('td').getElementById('perHour')[0].value;
  var lnHrs = mainRow.getElementsByTagName('td').getElementById('lineHours')[0].value;
  var total = mainRow.getElementsByTagName('td').getElementById('lineTotal')[0];
  var myResult = AmtPerHour * lnHrs;
  total.value = myResult;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Item Name</th>
    <th>Item Description</th>
    <th>Amount Per Hour</th>
    <th>Total Hours</th>
    <th>Line Total</th>
  </tr>
  
  <tbody id="addItems"></tbody>
</table>

<p>
  <button type="button" onclick="addItem();">
    Add Item
  </button>
</p>

<p>
  Amount Due: $0.00
  <script type="text/javascript">
    //add the amounts from all items.
    //if none added then have it set to zero.
  </script>
</p>

<p>
  Due Date:
  <script type="text/javascript">
    //start it 2 weeks from actual date
  </script>
</p>

<p>
  <input id="invoice_submit" type="submit" name="submit">
</p>
```

my biggest concern is the values not appearing.

Second problem, but one I can live with:
For rows, row1, row2, row3. if I delete row2, I would like it to then be row1, row2.
Right now it is row1, row3. I am talking about the # table section.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Hi please find below working snippet solving your first and second problems.
I made a few fixes to your code.

1. your data was not showing because `getElementById` expects you to pass element ID as string but you were passing element to it so this `document.getElementById(elem)` wont work.
2. you were calculating line total when that field is getting blurred but you should calculate line total also when user makes changes to either `amount per hour` or `total hours` so I added onblur to those fields also.
3. your delete row was deleting the first row always no matter which row I am trying to delete (`document.getElementById("addItems").deleteRow(0);` *will always delete the first row in table*) so I added the row reference to that function and now it deletes the appropriate row.
4. I added a Due Amount Total method to your Javascript to calculate due amount every time table is updated(insert/delete row) and updates the label value *Amount Due: $0.00*
5. I added the logic to renumber all the rows whenever a row is deleted. (*your second problem is no more so dont live with it* :) ).

```js
var renumber = 0;

// trigger everytime there is change in the table row to calculate the new due amount.
function calculateDueAmount() {
  var tblRows = document.getElementById("addItems").getElementsByTagName('tr');
  let total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < tblRows.length; i++) {
    let lineTotal = tblRows[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[5].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
    total += Number(lineTotal)
  }
  document.getElementById("amountDue").innerText = total.toFixed(2);
}
// no changes required in this
function addItem() {
  renumber++;
  var html = "<tr>";
  html += "<td id='itemNum'>" + renumber + "</td>";
  html += "<td><input name='itemName[]'></td>";
  html += "<td><input name='itemDescription[]'></td>";
  html += "<td><span class='currency'>$</span><input id='perHour' onblur='lineTotal(this);' value='0' name='amountPerHour[]'></td>";
  html += "<td><input id='lineHours' onblur='lineTotal(this);' value='0' name='hours[]'></td>";
  html += "<td><span class='currency'>$</span><input id='lineTotal' onblur='lineTotal(this);' value='0' name='lineTotal[]'></td>";
  html += "<td><button type='button' id='remove_button' onclick='removeItem(this);'> X </button></td>";
  html += "</tr>";
  document.getElementById("addItems").insertRow().innerHTML = html;
}
// updated and sanitized the logic to delete the row
function removeItem(elem) {

  let rowToDelete = elem.parentElement.parentElement;
  let rowNumber = rowToDelete.getElementsByTagName('td')[0].innerText;
  document.getElementById("addItems").deleteRow(rowNumber - 1);
  let tblRows = document.getElementById('addItems').getElementsByTagName('tr');
  let j = 0;
  for (; j < tblRows.length; j++) {
    tblRows[j].getElementsByTagName('td')[0].innerText = j + 1
  }
  calculateDueAmount(); // calculate due amount since row got deleted.
  renumber = j;
}

function lineTotal(elem) {
  var mainRow = elem.parentElement.parentElement;
  var AmtPerHour = mainRow.getElementsByTagName('td')[3].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
  var lnHrs = mainRow.getElementsByTagName('td')[4].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
  var total = mainRow.getElementsByTagName('td')[5].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
  var myResult = Number(AmtPerHour) * Number(lnHrs);
  total.value = myResult;
  calculateDueAmount(); // calculate due amount since row got added
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Item Name</th>
    <th>Item Description</th>
    <th>Amount Per Hour</th>
    <th>Total Hours</th>
    <th>Line Total</th>
  </tr>

  <tbody id="addItems"></tbody>
</table>

<p>
  <button type="button" onclick="addItem();">
    Add Item
  </button>
</p>

<p>
  Amount Due: $<span id="amountDue">0.00</span>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    //add the amounts from all items.
    //if none added then have it set to zero.
  </script>
</p>

<p>
  Due Date:
  <script type="text/javascript">
    //start it 2 weeks from actual date
  </script>
</p>

<p>
  <input id="invoice_submit" type="submit" name="submit">
</p>
```